# Extend a class from a declaration interface in Typescript

Tags: class, interface, typescript, declaration, extend

Is there any way to treat an interface or a variable inside a typescript declaration file like class to be able to extend a class from it?

Like this:

```
declare module "tedious" {

   import events = module('events');

   export class Request extends event.EventEmitter {
       constructor (sql: string, callback: Function);
       addParameter(name: string, type: any, value: string):any;
       addOutputParameter(name: string, type: any): any;
       sql:string;
       callback: Function;
   };

}
```

Right now i have to redefine the EventEmitter interface like this and use my own EventEmitter declaration.

```
import events = module('events');

class EventEmitter implements events.NodeEventEmitter{
    addListener(event: string, listener: Function);
    on(event: string, listener: Function): any;
    once(event: string, listener: Function): void;
    removeListener(event: string, listener: Function): void;
    removeAllListener(event: string): void;
    setMaxListeners(n: number): void;
    listeners(event: string): { Function; }[];
    emit(event: string, arg1?: any, arg2?: any): void;
}

export class Request extends EventEmitter {
    constructor (sql: string, callback: Function);
    addParameter(name: string, type: any, value: string):any;
    addOutputParameter(name: string, type: any): any;
    sql:string;
    callback: Function;
};
```

And extend it later inside my TypeScript File

```
import tedious = module('tedious');

class Request extends tedious.Request {
   private _myVar:string; 
   constructor(sql: string, callback: Function){
       super(sql, callback);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno about back in 2013, but now it's easy enough:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import * as events from "events";

class foo extends events.EventEmitter  {
   constructor() {
      super();
   }

   someFunc() { 
      this.emit('doorbell');
   }
}
```

I was looking for the answer to this, and finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine e.g.:

```
// Code in a abc.d.ts 
declare module "tedious" {
   export class Request  {
       constructor (sql: string, callback: Function);
       addParameter(name: string, type: any, value: string):any;
       addOutputParameter(name: string, type: any): any;
       sql:string;
       callback: Function;
   };
}

// Your code: 
///<reference path='abc.d.ts'/>
import tedious = module('tedious');

class Request extends tedious.Request {
   private _myVar:string; 
   constructor(sql: string, callback: Function){
       super(sql, callback);
   }
}
```

*Anything you put in your file you can put in a .d.ts file.*

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20module%20%22tedious%22%20%7B%0A%20%20%20export%20class%20Request%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20%28sql%3a%20string,%20callback%3a%20Function%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20addParameter%28name%3a%20string,%20type%3a%20any,%20value%3a%20string%29%3aany;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20addOutputParameter%28name%3a%20string,%20type%3a%20any%29%3a%20any;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sql%3astring;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback%3a%20Function;%0A%20%20%20%7D;%0A%7D%0A%0A//%20Your%20code%3a%20%0Aimport%20tedious%20=%20module%28%27tedious%27%29;%0A%0Aclass%20Request%20extends%20tedious.Request%20%7B%0A%20%20%20private%20_myVar%3astring;%20%0A%20%20%20constructor%28sql%3a%20string,%20callback%3a%20Function%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28sql,%20callback%29;%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: But then i would miss all the EventEmitter implementations and Typescript would thow a missing Property error. That's why i redefined the NodeJS EventEmmiter class in the first place.